# Adding extra field to TYPO3 extension table

Tags: php, typo3

I'm trying to add new field to `td_calendar` extension. I created new extension in Kickstarter and add extra field. Now I'm trying do display the data from table on site using `marker` method.

When I insert this code:

```
$markerArray['###ADDITIONAL_LINK###'] = $row['tx_tdcallendaradditionalfield_additional_link'] ? $this->cObj->wrap($this->makeLink($row['tx_tdcallendaradditionalfield_additional_link']), $this->conf['itemLinkWrap']) : '';
```

into `tx_tdcalendar_pi1_singleView.php` and `###ADDITIONAL_LINK###` marker in `tmpl` files, everything works fine (the additional link is displayed on site), but I want to do it right, so I created two new files in my extension folder:

- `ext_localconf.php`
- `class.tx_tdcallendaradditionalfield_additional_link.php`

In `ext_localconf.php` I insert this piece of code:

```
<?php
if (!defined ('TYPO3_MODE')) die ('Access denied.');

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['td_calendar']['extraItemMarkerHook'][] = 'EXT:td_callendar_additional_field/class.tx_tdcallendaradditionalfield_additional_link.php:tx_tdcallendaradditionalfield_additional_link';

?>
```

And in `class.tx_tdcallendaradditionalfield_additional_link.php` this code:

```
<?php
class tx_tdcallendaradditionalfield_additional_link {

    function buildSingleOutput($row){
      $SingleViewT = $this->cObj->getSubpart($this->templateCode, '###SINGLE_VIEW###');
      $markerArray = array(); // Simple markers
      $markerArray['###ADDITIONAL_LINK###'] = $row['tx_tdcallendaradditionalfield_additional_link'] ? $this->cObj->wrap($this->makeLink($row['tx_tdcallendaradditionalfield_additional_link']), $this->conf['itemLinkWrap']) : '';
      return $this->cObj->substituteMarkerArrayCached($SingleViewT, $markerArray, $subpartsArray);
    }
}
?>
```

But it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get PHP errors or no output? Is your class loaded (try it with a ```die()``` statement)? As a side note: The extension is called "td_calendar", your extension uses the letter L twice in the extension name.

Comment: Nothing happens - it seems like that code is not executed, and I know about double L letter (it's typo...)

Comment: Are you sure the extension has an extraItemMarkerHook? This is not a TYPO3 core concept, but a concept integrated by extensions such as tt_news or tt_address. I didn't find it in td_calendar. Did you check on this? Which version of TYPO3 are you using?

Comment: I thought that is native TYPO3 function... I found it in some tutorial (about tt_news ext)

Comment: What is your TYPO3 version? You still may get it done by XCLASSing the method.